# how add a field in the customer module in the odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-16

I'm trying to add a field in the customer module
But it looks like there is an error because "department_name" field and "option_units" field are not showing in partner module
What is the problem?

views.xml

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record id="partner_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
      <field name="name">Partners</field>
      <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
    <menuitem id="receipt_menu_root" name="Receipt Units"/>
    <menuitem id="partner_menu_main" name="Partners" action="partner_menu_action" parent="receipt_menu_root"/>

    <record id="res_partner_customizations_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.customizations.form</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="mobile" position="after">
                <field name="department_name"/>
            </field>
            <field name="email" position="after">
                <field name="option_units"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

and models.py

from odoo import models, fields, api

```
# PARTNERS //////////////////////////////////////////////////
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    department_name = fields.Char(string="Department")
    option_units = fields.Selection([
        ('room3','Room 3'),
        ('room4','Romm 4'),
        ('room5','Room 5')
    ],string='Options')
```

Comment: IIRC the right fields group in the partner view (phone, mobile, email, etc.) is changed very much by other odoo modules, so much that there are `div`s around those fields, which makes it a bit difficult to add other fields at those positions.

Comment: For example: the `sms` and the `mail` modules change a lot.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Have you created your own custom module ? See documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/administration/odoo_sh/getting_started/first_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding a new field in the inherited model `res.partner` by the XPath method.
in your case, you can replace your XML code like this:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_partner_form_option_units">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit.option_units</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="XML">
                <xpath expr=expr="//field[@name='is_subcon']" position="after">
                    <field name="option_units"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```